# Change HDFS replication factor

Tags: filesystems, hadoop, distributed-filesystems, hdfs

I've changed replication factor from 3 to 2 for some directories with command:

```
hdfs dfs -setrep -R 2 /path/to/dir
```

but my HDFS free space still the same. Should I do something else to free my disks?

Answer (score 0):

Changing replication factor don't affect existing blocks stored on HDFS. so that is expected.
If possible you can delete and re-load the data to satisfy your needs, However, its recommended to have replication factor of at least 3.

Comment: I found out that "dfs -setrep" changed replication factor of existing files, I just needed to wait some time and restart data nodes